# How to query logged in users across domains?

Tags: windows-7

I am working from a Windows 7 Professional PC on DOMAIN1, but I would like to be able to query the users currently logged in to a Windows 7 Professional PC on DOMAIN2. My DOMAIN1\username is a local admin on the DOMAIN2 PC and admin on my DOMAIN1 PC.

I've tried running query user normally from my DOMAIN1 PC:

```
query user /SERVER:DOMAIN2PC
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
```

I've also tried it with psexec:

```
psexec \\DOMAIN2PC query user

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access DOMAIN2PC:
The network path was not found.

Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on DOMAIN2PC.
```

I've tried it with PSLoggedOn:

```
psloggedon \\DOMAIN2PC

PsLoggedon v1.34 - See who's logged on
Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error opening HKEY_USERS for \\DOMAIN2PC
Unable to query resource logons
```

The results are the same if I use an IP address instead.

**If I log in to another PC on DOMAIN2 (with my local admin DOMAIN1 credentials), then the  `query user /SERVER:DOMAIN2PC` works perfectly.**
I only have the problem when trying to talk across the domains.

Can anybody suggest what I can do to remotely query the list of users on a DOMAIN2 PC while working from DOMAIN1?

Comment: in powershell as admin `query session /server:Domain2PC`

Comment: @Nazard - `query session` produces a similar error as `query user`. `Error 1722 getting sessionnames`

Comment: The account you are running it from must be a domain administrator. Is yours? Try running it from the DC server as a domain admin and see if you get the same results.

Comment: The account is local administrator on both `DOMAIN1PC` and `DOMAIN2PC`. It is not a domain administrator.

Comment: Domain admin blankets the permissions, but the specific permission can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753032(v=ws.11).aspx alsos ee remarks section here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490800.aspx

Comment: If I didn't have Query Information access permission then I would expect I could not run the query regardless of the domain I was on. But, I do succeed if I'm using the same credentials to query a DOMAIN2 PC from another DOMAIN2 PC.